# Library versioning: Typescript / ES5

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I want to write a small runtime environment independent library for managing general trees and I have a doubt on how to package / distribute the library after it's finished.

I have the following in mind:

- Written in Typescript
- Create Typescript definition template (d.ts)
- Transpile to ES6 / ES5 and distribute as a node module
- Possibility to use as a node module on the server, but also in the browser (commonjs / AMD compliant, but also just working without module loader / build step);

I've looked into the dist folder of ImmutableJS on Github to see how they do it, and got a bit confused:

- It is written in ES2015
- There is a TS definition template defined
- But the ES5 version (immutable.js) does not seem generated (it looks like hand-written code). https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/dist/immutable.js

Hence, I wondered if they wrote the library in both ES2015 / ES5 (in parallel) and what influence this has on maintenance / syncing versioning.

It appears as if the ES5 version was written specifically for the browser (non-TS). Can you give me some pointers on what's happening here?

Comment: I would suggest to get inspiration from more packages than just Immutable. RxJS and Angular 2 are good examples of how TS projects can be published.

Comment: Also see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html